# I created an online catalogue website and when uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number reserving s book

Tags: javascript, php

the code for researving after searching and getting the book is:

```
foreach($results as $book){
                    $cat=$searcher->decryptcategory($book['Category']);
                    $html=$html.<<<html
                    <div class="search-result">
                        <p class="result-title">{$book['Title']}</p>
                        <p class="result-content"><em>By:</em>{$book['Author']}</p>
                        <p class="result-content"><em>Category:</em>{$book['Category']}</p>
                        <p class="result-content" id="bkisbn"><em>ISBN </em>{$book['ISBN']}</p>
                        <p class="result-content">{$book['Abstract']}</p>
                        <br>

                        <input type="button" class="go-button" id="reserve-book" onclick="initReservation({$book['ISBN']},true);" value="Reserve" />
                        <input type="button" class="bad-button" id="unreserve-book" onclick="initReservation({$book['ISBN']},false);" value="Release" />        
                    </div>
```

html;

the javascript for reserving is:

```
function initReservation(isbn,reserve){

 if (reserve)
 var url="reservations.php?isbn="+isbn+"&action=reserve";
 if (!reserve){ url="reservations.php?isbn="+isbn+"&action=release"; }
 ajaxGet(url,
    function(req){
        showModal(req.responseText);
        alert("response "+req.responseText+"  "+isbn+" "+reserve);
    },
    function(err){
        showModal(err);
    }
    );
```

the "ISBN" is a string

Comment: You have to be as specific as you can in order to get a good response to your post. where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: When I reserve a book with an isbn that's an integer it works fine and when I reserve one with a string isbn it gives the error..it says its on line 1 of my search.php but line one has <!doctype html> and my search.php starts with a <php and no <!doctype html> which is at the generate.php which generates my page

Comment: First of all, you have nit included the code of your `search.php`. second, since you are making `ajax` call and from what I can see in your code, you are calling `reservations.php` file. so why as you say, `search.php` file is generating the error?!

Comment: You 1st search for the book using search.php and once you get it press a button reserve which makes the ajax call and then calling the reservation.php file and the file is called when the isbn is an integer but not when its a string

Comment: When you have not included the code which is generating the error, how are we supposed to be able to find your error?!

Comment: <div class="search-bar">
    <input class="text" onchange="startSearch()" type="search" placeholder="Type Search Term(s)" value="" id="queryTx" name="querystring" />
 <input class="search-button" onclick="startSearch()" type="button" value="Search" id="searchbtn" name="startsearch" />
 <input type="hidden" name="location" id="loc" value="lib" /> 
 </div>
<div class="search-results" id="results-div"></div>

Comment: This is the search.pho

Comment: Please edit you original post and add the code in the original post so it will be readable.

Comment: also from what I can see in you comment, it depends on the `function startSearch()` which again you have not included it's code. this way no one will bother themselves to help you. please read the instruction on how to post your question one more time. and then edit your post and add all the necessary data which is required!